# Toggle and untoggle a DropdownMenu's appearance

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have an `Icon` . And when the `Icon` is clicked it toggles the `expanded` state variable. The `expanded` state variable toggles a `DropdownMenu`. And that `DropdownMenu` appears underneath the `Icon`.

`DropdownMenu` has a `onDismissRequest` callback. `onDismissRequest` runs when the user clicks outside the `DropdownMenu`. `onDismissRequest` toggles the `expanded` state variable, and so closes the `DropdownMenu`.

However, if the user clicks outside `DropdownMenu`, and specifically on the icon, `onDismissRequest` sets `expanded` to `false`. But the user has also clicked on the `Icon`. And the `Icon` sets `expanded` to `true`.

And so, clicking on the icon again does not close the `DropdownMenu`: it opens it.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
  var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  Column() {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "",
      Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded }
    )
    DropdownMenu(expanded, { expanded = false }) {
      DropdownMenuItem({ }) {
        Text("Menu item")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, how can I toggle and untoggle a `DropdownMenu`'s appearance?

If I could make `onDismissRequest` swallow all the interactions I could prevent my `Icon`'s click listener opening the menu again--but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: I don't have this behaviour. Are you sure about `expanded`? You are using `expand` and `expanded`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `clickable` when it's not expanded:

```
.clickable(enabled = !expand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the clicking on the icon only opening the dropdown menu, instead of toggling it:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "",
      Modifier.clickable { expand = true }
)
```

Also, make clicking on any of the dropdown menu items to close the menu:

```
DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expand = false})
```

That way, clicking the icon will only expand the dropdown, and clicking on any dropdown item or anywhere else will close it.

Comment: Clicking elsewhere will set `expand` to `false`. But if that elsewhere is the icon, then `expand` will then be `true` again.

Comment: When you click the icon, it will only expand the dropdown - nothing else. Clicking elsewhere or any menu item will close the dropdown - which is the expected behavior of a dropdown - not disabling the icon button. This solution works just fine.